# remove particle animation on javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

So i have a template that i'm using on wordpress and doing small adjustments to make it the way i want
although now there is an animation on the header done with javascript and i wanted to "eliminate"
i will post the code for the mentioned event:

```js
    // Breadcrumb effect  
        //if ($(".dt_pagetitle .canvas").length) {
            let cnvs = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            c2d = cnvs.getContext("2d");
            cnvs.width = window.innerWidth, cnvs.height = window.innerHeight;
            let particlesArray = [];
            window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                cnvs.width = window.innerWidth, cnvs.height = window.innerHeight
            });
            let cursor = {
                x: null,
                y: null
            };
            cnvs.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                cursor.x = e.pageX, cursor.y = e.pageY;
                for (let t = 0; t < 10; t++) particlesArray.push(new particles)
            }), cnvs.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
                cursor.x = e.pageX, cursor.y = e.pageY;
                for (let t = 0; t < 10; t++) particlesArray.push(new particles)
            });
            class particles {
                constructor() {this.x = cursor.x, this.y = cursor.y, this.size = 10 * Math.random() + 1, this.speedX = 3 * Math.random() - 1.5, this.speedY = 3 * Math.random() - 1.5, this.color = "blue"}
                update() {this.x += this.speedX, this.y += this.speedY, this.size > .2 && (this.size -= .1)}
                draw() {c2d.strokeStyle = this.color, c2d.lineWidth = .4, c2d.beginPath(), c2d.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI), c2d.stroke()}
            }
            let hndlParticles = () => {
                for (let e = 0; e < particlesArray.length; e++) particlesArray[e].update(), particlesArray[e].draw(), particlesArray[e].size <= .3 && (particlesArray.splice(e, 1), e--)
            }
            let anim = () => {
                c2d.clearRect(0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height), hndlParticles(), requestAnimationFrame(anim)
            }
            anim();
        //}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
```

i was able to remove it using the development of the browser by turning  off both events (mouseclick and mousemove), although wanted to make it in a permanent way

things i have tried:

1. delete the code from the mentioned file, although i don't want this approach due to the fact if the templates does get some update i would had eventually to delete the code manually once again

although it is important to refer that even though i eliminated this code from the file the animation still was running and inspecting the file on the browser i still could see the code (strange i know) thought initially was a cache issue, so cleared it and still ended with the same result

2. tried using a removeEventListener although to the lack of knowledge i have on javascript wasn't successfull either

with this said i'm trying to look for some help on this matter, where i could implement some js code and import it on the functions.php child theme

Comment: can you clarify what you actually want to do

Comment: i want to remove the particle  animation from my website

Comment: but you cant just remove the code?

Comment: try chatting on the stackoverflow javascript chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this to this functions.php of your child theme

```
<?php
function add_custom_js() {
    ?>
    <script>
        //  JavaScript code here

            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            canvas.addEventListener = override;

            function override(type, callback, mode) {
                return false;
            }

    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_custom_js', 0);
```

what it attempts to do is run before the other event listeners are added, then override the addeventlistener method on that canvas element to do nothing

it does depend on when exactly the other event listeners are actually added though

you need that canvas element to have been parsed by the browser and then run the override code before its own event listeners have been added

so instead of using `wp_head` you'd need to add it something like `wp_body` or `wp_footer`

Comment: can you mark it as the accepted answer for me